# UN wrapping the the wrapped stored procedure oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have come across the scenario where  we have to modify the stored procedure but when we opened it the stored procedure is  in wrapped form.for modifying it we have to UN-wrap it 
i have found some online sites for doing this but i cant post my code there

my question is their some utilty for oracle that can do it i am not asking for some online site

Comment: i am searching for some utilty for oracle not for some online site for un wrapping @xing

Comment: Requests for tools/software are off-topic on SO. Give http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ a try.

Comment: If his is code that you own, you should be able to start from the code in source control without unwrapping the code.  If you don't have the source, that strongly implies that you're trying to access code you don't have authorization to view.  There is no supported way to unwrap code (that would defeat the purpose).  The wrapping algorithm changes in different versions.  You can certainly find white papers that talk about the algorithms in use and build your own unwrapper like the folks that run the various sites you've found have done.

Comment: hi all actually what i was looking for unwrap the wrap code without putting it  online and finally found the solution
use plsql developer and add unwrapper utility for it

https://www.salvis.com/blog/plsql-unwrapper-for-sql-developer/